# How to run python script on the Tor network

Tags: python, security, tor

I'm writing a program in python and was trying to make it run through the tor network instead of statically.
how do I do it? I'm using python 3.8, tor 10.0.6 and win 10. all I need is connect to a https website

Comment: if you want to connect to webpage using `tor` then you have to use `proxy server` which is run by `tor` - in modules like `requests` you should have `requests.get(..., proxy=...)` to use `tor` in connection. BTW: in the same way you use `tor` with normal web browser - in web browser settings you have to set `tor` as proxy server.

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed `Tor` then it should work as proxy server `127.0.0.1:9050` and you can use it in modules like `requests`

In example I use portal `httpbin.org` to test my IP

```
import requests

proxy = {
    'http':  'socks5://localhost:9050',
    'https': 'socks5://localhost:9050',
}

url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy)  # using TOR network
#print(r.text)
print('   Tor IP:', r.json()['origin'])

r = requests.get(url)
#print(r.text)
print('normal IP:', r.json()['origin'])
```

and this moment it shows me:

```
   Tor IP: 146.59.155.27
normal IP: 217.99.86.56
```

---

But this will use almost all time the same `Tor IP`.

If you want to change `IP` then you have to restart `Tor`.

Or you would have to configure `ControlPort` and `Password` in `Tor` settings (on Linux in file `/etc/tor/torrc`)

and then you can change `Tor IP` by sending signal with socket

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('localhost', 9051))
s.send('AUTHENTICATE "your_passord"\r\nSIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n'.encode())
```

or you can use module `stem` for this

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate(password='your_password')
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

You can find many questions on `Stackoverflow` which better describe it.

---

As I know after sending signal it may need few seconds to get new `Tor IP` so you may have to wait before next request.